# MongoDB $cmp (aggregation) giving false results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using the cmp aggregation in mongo and got it working but I think the issue I'm running into is a bug. When I compare 10(or greater) to say 8.3, -1 is returned. When I compare 9.5 to 8.3, 1 is returned. It seems as if I compare any number in tenths place or above to a number in ones place I get a -1. If I compare a ones to ones it works fine.

Below are the parts that compare and the results

```
 cmpPrice: {
                $cmp: ['$amount', '$ticker.price_usd']
              },

case "price":
                    if (doc.cmpPrice == -1 && doc.direction == "above") {
                      console.log("\t\tConditions Met, Price Above" );   
                      emailUser(doc);
                    } else if (doc.cmpPrice == 1 && doc.direction == "below") {
                      console.log("\t\tConditions Met, Price Below");
                      emailUser(doc);
                    } else {
                      console.log("\t\tFailed");
                    }
                    break;
```

results

```
       - ID: 59766722b006792254355adb
                Amount 10
                Ticker Price 7.79818
                Conditions( price, above )
                CMP( Volume: -1, Market Cap: -1, Price: -1 )
                Conditions Met, Price Above
        - ID: 597659d5dd06792ea08037e9
                Amount 100
                Ticker Price 7.79818
                Conditions( price, below )
                CMP( Volume: -1, Market Cap: -1, Price: -1 )
                Failed
        - ID: 5976624daccd002bdce2ec6a
                Amount 9.5
                Ticker Price 7.79818
                Conditions( price, above )
                CMP( Volume: 1, Market Cap: 1, Price: 1 )
                Failed
```

Comment: Silly question, but are both Amount and Ticker Price of type Number?

Comment: Amount is a String, and Number is taken from an API json, so I'm guessing string too

Comment: Can you make "Amount" of type Number and try again? And check the typeof "Ticker Price"? I think there might be a problem between types.

Comment: Changed amount to a number and put in my own number value for "Ticker Price and it works(it was a string). Is there a way to change the typeof for Ticker Price to a number within the aggregate'

Comment: Wrote an answer summarising the problem. To change the typeof for Ticker Price, use parseInt when fetching the data from the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that both types (that of **Amount** and **Ticker Price**) are of the same type (either a Number of a String). Remember that the $cmp aggregation operator compares *both value and type*. If the types do not match, [the BSON Comparison Order applies.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/)

The problem with your code is most likely that the types do not match and BSON comparison rules plays its part. I suggest making **Amount** a number, and converting **Ticker Price** to a number.